# javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.SetSupport.doEndTag

Tags: jsp, jstl

New to JSTL and been trying to lower case a variable in in JSTL. I tried this

```
<c:set value="${fn:toLowerCase(confirmedStatus)}" />
```

and added taglib

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Where confirmedStatus is a enumerator variable.

This is the error

```
    Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.SetSupport.doEndTag(SetSupport.java:245)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tiles.clientOrder_jsp._jspx_meth_c_set_0(clientOrder_jsp.java:599)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tiles.clientOrder_jsp._jspx_meth_c_when_1(clientOrder_jsp.java:561)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tiles.clientOrder_jsp._jspx_meth_c_choose_1(clientOrder_jsp.java:516)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tiles.clientOrder_jsp._jspx_meth_c_when_0(clientOrder_jsp.java:486)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tiles.clientOrder_jsp._jspx_meth_c_choose_0(clientOrder_jsp.java:452)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tiles.clientOrder_jsp._jspx_meth_c_forEach_0(clientOrder_jsp.java:389)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tiles.clientOrder_jsp._jspService(clientOrder_jsp.java:154)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:558)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:489)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:972)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:417)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:906)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:178)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1015)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:700)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
```

Comment: Normal users google for answers by simply copypasting the exception message + 1st line of stacktrace. When putting them in the question title, they will find this Q&A much sooner. So please do not destroy the SEO by rolling back the edit and putting back a terrible title like "JSTL JSP exception" which could basically be applied on every single problem with JSP and JSTL whereby "an exception" is thrown ;)

Comment: @BalusC You're right about the roll back, while im not a "normal" user, I'm an "average" user, still learning and cant tell right away which line in the huge error list is the actual issue, Make your point without being condescending.

Comment: It's just the bottommost root cause. This is not specific to JSP/JSTL, this is always the case in all Java exceptions. I.e. it's just basic Java. All exceptions which are thrown thereafter (there above) are just consequences. Keep this in mind when you face an exception again ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `<c:set>` is missing a `var` attribute, otherwise what are you setting?

```
<c:set var="myvar" value="${fn:toLowerCase(confirmedStatus)}" />
```